# Powershell get window name and sendkeys

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, window, sendkeys

I have a script which loops until it finds an internet explorer window and then sends keys to it (see bellow). My problem is that I cannot send keys to window after AppActivate function as it does not focus the "File name" box where the keys should be entered. (see my code bellow)

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$ScriptDone = 'False'
$val=0

While ($ScriptDone = 'False') 
{ 
    if($wshell.AppActivate('Choose File to Upload'))
    {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('a')
        Break
    } 

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    $val++
    Write-Host $val

    if ($val -eq 60)
    {
        $ScriptDone='True'
    }
}
```

Also a screenshot bellow showing how pop up window looks like.

[Pop up box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZDf0.jpg)

Is there a way not to activate the window but to check if it exists instead? I would just like to replace the AppActivate function if possible.

Or second option is there a way to activate the "File name" box in the "Choose File to Upload window" ?

Comment: As for … "I have a script which loops until it finds an internet explorer window"
… So, you have an infinite loop that is just grabbing any random IE open instance, randomly, and trying to use that to upload a file? Why? What are you trying to do?
What does this loop script look like? What are you not using the built-in cmdlets for interacting with websites, thus no need for sendleys.

Comment: My main goal is to upload a file to internet.

I have a vba program which clicks the button "upload in the internet" in a site and a "choose file to upload" window appears and then my vba is on hold and cannot handle this window.

I am trying to build a powershell script which would just handle that pop up window.

Idea is when i start my vba code also start a powershell script which loops until it finds a pop up and handles it by entering a path to a file and pressing ''enter' or 'open' button to upload it.

Could you help me with that please?